# apache VFS with res and zip together

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

I would expect this work.

```
FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();

FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager.resolveFile("zip:res:hello.zip");
```

But I'm getting URI "res:hello.zip" is not an absolute file name.

---

With this I'm successfully getting my zip file, but not the files within the zip.

```
FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();

FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager.resolveFile("res:hello.zip");
```

---

I have to wrap the zip lookup with a lookup of the url from a res lookup. This gets me a fileObject with the contents of the zip file.

```
FileSystemManager fileSystemManager = VFS.getManager();

FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager.resolveFile("zip:" + fileSystemManager.resolveFile("res:hello.zip").getURL());
```

How can I use zip and res together without the ugly wrap call?

Comment: did you try res:zip:hello.zip? it seems more logically correct: first access resource and then recoginize the fact that it is a zip.

Comment: Yes, that was my first "what if I do this..." type reaction. That and many others all failed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
FileObject fileObject = fileSystemManager.resolveFile("zip:res://hello.zip");
```